# How to specify IBM Containers' IP to register

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

I use Secure Gateway to integrate my apps on Bluemix with On-premise resources.
I read the following instruction:

https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SecureGateway/sg_023.html#sg_033

I successfully setup white list for CF apps. But I can't set IP address for IBM Containers(Docker) because I don't know how to specify Containers' IPs to register  ip table of Secure gateway.

[image]

Does anyone know how to specify valid ip addresses of IBM Containers?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

It looks you are specifying the private IP address of your container (172.30.0.5) and what you should do is to bind your container to a public IP address and use this new IP to configure your Secure Gateway.

Here are the steps to bind your container to a public IP address:

1) Optional: request IP (if not done that already)

```
$ cf ic ip request
```

2) Optional: if you have already requested IP you can use the following command to see which IPs are available for your organization:

```
$ cf ic ip list
```

3) Bind an IP address to your container

```
$ cf ic ip bind <ip_address> <container id>
```

After that you have to wait a few minutes to wait for it to complete and then you can use the public IP address in the Secure Gateway.

You can do this in the UI as well, just select the pull down menu after the Public IP and select one available from the list:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your advise! I tried to set Public IP, but I couldn’t find Public IP fields because We use Container groups.
As far as I know, we can’t add extra Public IPs in case of container groups. I want to know how to specify IPs to register in case of container groups.

Comment: For a containers group you can specify a route, actually you cannot request a public IP address for a containers group.

Comment: Hi, I issued nslookup command to resolve my DNS route to IP addresses and registered IP addresses to Secure Gateway's ip tables, but "Connection refused" was occured on my container...